# Privoxy still blocks my pip install comand even though it's not installed anymore

Tags: privoxy

I had privoxy installed on Ubuntu 20.04 and then I uninstalled it using `apt remove privoxy`.

Right now there isnt any directory or file named privoxy or service named privoxy but when I try to install a pip or yarn package in terminal it tells me it was blocked by Privoxy
What can I do to remove it completely?

Answer (score 0):

Your command should be:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove privoxy
```

[reference](https://linoxide.com/install-use-privoxy-ubuntu-16-04/)

If that doesn't completely remove it,you can also try `sudo apt --purge autoremove`

Comment: But I've already removed it with "sudo apt remove privoxy" and when I try this command it tells me privoxy isn't installed

Comment: @H2349309 I added a further command for you to try.

Comment: I'm saying I can't remove it (no matter what apt remove command I try) because it says it's not installed in the first place. And there is no folder or file named privoxy anywhere. And yet it blocks my pip,yarn and npm install commands.